# Match a serie in a chart with ComponentQuery

Tags: extjs, charts, series

I'm using ExtJS 4 with MVC. I have a chart with two series: line and column. When clicking a column I need to trigger an event.

In the controller, I used the following query to match the column series, but  doesn't work.

```
this.control({
    '#companyChartItemId[series[type=column]]': {
        itemmouseup:this.onItemMouseUp
    }
});
```

Any thoughts how could I match it?

Below is my code:

**app/view/company/Chart.js**

```
Ext.define('Market.view.company.Chart', {
    extend: 'Ext.chart.Chart',
    xtype: 'companyChart',
    requires: ['Market.store.HistoricalMarketData'],
    theme: 'Category1',
    store:'HistoricalMarketData',
    initComponent: function() {
        this.callParent();
    },
    axes: [{
        type: 'Numeric',
        position: 'left',
        fields: ['close'],
        title: 'Price',
        grid: true
    }, {
        type: 'Numeric',
        position: 'right',
        fields: ['volume'],
        title: 'Volume',
        grid: true
    }, {
        type: 'Category',
        position: 'bottom',
        fields: ['time'],
        title: 'Month of the Year'
    }],

    series: [{
        type: 'column',
        axis: 'right',
        xField: 'time',
        yField: 'volume',
        highlight: true,
        markerConfig: {
            type: 'cross',
            size: 3
        }
    }, {
        type: 'line',
        axis: 'left',
        smooth: false,
        fill: false,
        fillOpacity: 0.8,
        xField: 'time',
        yField: 'close'
    }]
});
```

**app/controller/ChartController.js**

```
Ext.define('Market.controller.ChartController', {
    extend:'Ext.app.Controller',
    stores:['MarketData'],
    init: function() {
        this.control({
            '#companyChartItemId[series[type=column]]': {
                itemmouseup:this.onItemMouseUp
            }
        });
    },

    onItemMouseUp: function (item) {
        //do something
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just configure the listener/response function where you define your series. You can add listeners as a config in your series, check out the doc:
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.chart.series.Series-cfg-listeners